# How to find probability of forming an organisation with $3$ male students and $2$ female students if a particular male student must be included?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

There are $5$ male students and $6$ female students, $5$ students are needed to form an organisation.

- Find the probability that $3$ male students and $2$ female students are members of the organisation, a certain male student must be a member of the organisation.

This is my steps (4C2 * 6C2)/10C4

Please help me

Comment: Hi, you are expected to show what you have tried, and where you are stuck in order to get appropriate help.

Comment: Your steps seem right to me, you have 1 way to choose the certain male student, then 4 choose 2 ways to choose the rest of the males, and 6 choose 2 ways to fill the rest with females, so I think you are right

Answer (score 0):

First, the number of ways to pick $3$ boys and $2$ girls from $5$ boys and $6$ girls respectively is:

($5$ choose $3$)($6$ choose $2$) = $(10)(15)$ = $150$ ways.

Next, the number of ways to pick $5$ students from the $11$ candidates (excluding the rule of a certain boy to be picked) is:

($11$ choose $5$) = $462$

However, we have to exclude the cases where all the members are girls. The number of ways to pick $5$ girls from $6$ is:

($6$ choose $5$) = $6$

Now, subtracting this from the initial number of total ways of picking random students is $462-6 = 456$ ways.

Hence, the probability that 3 male students and 2 female students are members of the organization given that a certain male student must be a member of the organization is:

$\frac{150}{456} = \frac{25}{76} ≈ 32.89$ %